# C memory pool storing

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am writing small memory allocation system. Having:

```
typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;     /*size of memory pool*/
    void* memory; /*pointer to pool location in memory*/
} Pool;

Pool* allocatePool(int n) {
    Pool *myPool = malloc(sizeof(Pool) + n);

    if (myPool){
        myPool->size = n;
        myPool->memory = myPool+1;
    }

    return myPool;
}
```

I am trying to write function that will store arbitrary object of n size at location offset within the pool.

```
void store(Pool* pool, int offset, int size, void *object) {
    char *ptrHelper;                  
    ptrHelper = &(pool->memory);      /*copy pool memory address*/
    ptrHelper += offset;              /*increment to match offset*/
    memcpy(ptrHelper, &object, size); /*copy object in to the pool*/
}
```

Questions:

ptrHelper = &(pool->memory) is there another correct way of getting pool memory address?

What to do in case I want to store values grater than size of void *object (4 bytes in my case)?

How to correctly handle strings without changing functions parameter structure?
Thank you.

Comment: Why `&(pool->memory)` and not `pool->memory`? It seems that `pool->memory` is already a pointer to the pool. Why take its address? If `offset` is 0, won't you overwrite `pool->memory`?

Comment: pool->memory is base address for my pool. Incrementing it's address changes address of my pool and setting offset to 0 does nothing to my target address. I might be wrong. These are my first steps in to C :).

Comment: This is the second re-post! Just FYI: I flagged it for mod attention. stack overflow is not a tutorial site. If you lack the basics, please read a C book and start with something easier to get some practice first.

Comment: @Olaf I spoke with moderator about my posts.We came to conclusion that I should delete my previous posts and rephrase my question. So I did.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question. Anyway, we'll see what a mod does; I still think your question is too broad (and I'm not the only one apparently). No offence (honestly!), but you really should first get more practice in C and learn how to do some things in C. Memory management includes quite some parts of not strictly standard compliant operations a beginner should definitively avoid. I already see various - well - "problematic" issues. And your code is not conforming in parts is actually should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the best answer, but this might help...:

1. Your structure is wasting memory space - you don't need the pointer, as your memory block simply continues at the end of the structure. To access the memory block easily, you can use a [flexible (un-specified) length array at the end of your structure, known as a FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).
2. I don't think you need to name the struct using both a tag and a typedef alias - t's superfluous. You aren't going to use the struct's tag-name anyway, so just don't use one.
3. Your `store` function is misusing the pointers. For example: `object` is already a pointer, use it directly (don't take the pointer's address). The same goes for `ptrHelper` - it's already a pointer.

   **Taking a pointer's address** (using the `&` operator) **will return the pointer's location in the stack's memory address** (the location of the variable in the function), **NOT the data's location**.
4. As Olef pointed out - you're mixing signed and unsigned values, which is dangerous. I've changed the `size` type to `size_t` which is what you get from `size_of` and it's what `malloc` expects.

   If it's too big for you, you can use an unsigned int or unsigned short, depending on what you'll be using as an upper limit... however, this will make error handling a bit harder to manage.

Here's the same structure with an unsigned `size` property and using a FAM (flexible array member):

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;     /*size of memory pool*/
    char memory[]; /* the actual memory buffer, available as a byte array */
} Pool;

// sizeof(Pool) == sizeof(size_t) // the char[] array isn't part of the size.
```

This slight change also makes allocation easier:

```
Pool* allocatePool(size_t n) {
    Pool *myPool = malloc(sizeof(Pool) + n);

    if (myPool){
        myPool->size = n;
    }

    return myPool;
}
```

Something to think about - this structure and the allocation function require the user of your `Pool` object to access the memory using special semantics.

On the other hand, returning the `pool->memory` array instead of the `pool` object will allow your user to be agnostic, and you could implement a `malloc` alternative that fits straight in.

When you get a pointer back, you just need to calculate the offset to find the original `pool` object's location in the memory.

Have a look at the amazing [SDS String Library](https://github.com/antirez/sds) used by Redis - they have great ideas.

You can implement something similar using:

```
#define _get_pool_addr(p) ((p) - sizeof(Pool))

void* allocatePool(size_t n) {
    Pool *myPool = malloc(sizeof(Pool) + n);

    if (myPool){
        myPool->size = n;
    }

    return myPool->memory;
}

void freePool(void * pooled_memory) {
    Pool *myPool = _get_pool_addr(pooled_memory);
    // do what you want. If you're freeing the memory:
    free(myPool);
}
```

Using these changes, your `store` function is very straight forward:

```
void store(void * mymem, int offset, int size, void *object) {
    memcpy(mymem + offset, object, size); /*copy object in to the pool*/
}
```

This, I think, would be better then using a `store` function that looks like this (your version, just fixed):

```
void store(Pool* pool, int offset, int size, void *object) {
    char *ptrHelper;                  
    ptrHelper = pool->memory;      /*copy pool memory address*/
    ptrHelper += offset;              /*increment to match offset*/
    memcpy(ptrHelper, object, size); /*copy object in to the pool*/
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Quite some effort, but still some flaws. For a starter: mixing signed and unsigne integers should be handled very carefully. The `sizeof` operator yields an `size_t` and it should not be mixed with an `int`. And a general note: It is a bad idea to do OP's job. Better give some hints and explain the problem she has so he can write the code on her own. Otherwise he will not really learn.

Comment: "using an unnamed struct" - There is no "unnamed struct".

Comment: @Olaf - thanks. I was just fixing the parts related to the question (not the `int` v.s `size_t`), so thanks for the catch. As for the OP's job... I think he/she had most of it already performed, just had issues with pointer usage (and type mismatch, which I ignored)... but I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: I actually don't see much use in the question. That is no memory management, but just adding an unnecessary `size` to the allocated block. Unnecessary because `free` does not need it. Btw, your code is also wrong. Arithmetics on `void *` is undefined. And you have other undefined behaviour with alignment issues. Also don't use macros if a function can do the same job. If in doubt about performance (most times a bad idea for a early code), make it `static` and/or `inline`.

Comment: Ehm, there is also no anmonymous `struct`. Do you mean the FAM?

Comment: @Olaf ... no, I meant that the Pool struct isn't a named structure (I just define the type's name, without assigning a name to the structure)... I was fairly certain they're called anonymous structures, but I never remember names.... :-p

Comment: Your `struct` does have a name, resp. alias, it is `Pool`. Do you mena the missing _tag_? Yes, you should have made clear that is superfluous most times. Using the correct terms for a beginner's question is even more vital than for an expert (though answers should use correct terms here anyway). They will catch up the terms, use them in even more missleading contex later, ... confusion multiplied.

Comment: @Olaf - thanks! I guess I'm learning even more through this answer then the person asking the question :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. You all have been very helpful, especially Mr. Myst, thank you sir. :D.

Answer (score 0):

`ptrHelper = &(pool->memory)` does not give the pool memory address.
Use: `ptrHelper = pool->memory`